problem with reverse proxy angular application in docker container
I'm creating an application in angular that needs access to an API (not created by me) that unfortunately has a CORS policy that does not allow execution so I solved the problem by using reverse proxy locally everything works correctly and I can extract the data from the API the problem arises when I try to create a docker container as the url set as the proxy target is replaced with the container's url
proxy.conf.json
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "https://myurl",
      "secure": true,
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api": ""
      }
    }
  }

nginx.conf
server {

        listen 8081;
        server_name localhost;
    
        
    location /api/taxation_customs {
        proxy_pass https://myurl;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    
        
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }

Dockerfile
FROM node:latest AS build

WORKDIR /usr/local/app


COPY ./ /usr/local/app/


RUN npm install


RUN npm run build


FROM nginx:latest


COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist/generatore/browser /usr/share/nginx/html



COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 8081 

